# Expresion regular simple

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, http

chicos busco una expresion regular que me evalue esto `{}` sin importar si en el medio hay texto.

`/{}|\+/g, currentTime` esa es la expresion que tengo, la gracia seria que remplazara todo lo que esta entre llaves o sea, entre esas llaves ira una variable que repesenta texto, pero no me deja meter variables dentro de esas `{}` ya que me lo lee como texto y no como variable.

esta es la funcion que trato de hacer.

```
    let replaceData = (data,keyword,replacedata) =>{
    data.replace(/{keyword}|\+/g, replacedata)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes construir la regex con el objeto [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) y utilizar el valor que deseas reemplazar para hacerlo dinámico, ya que de otro modo no será posible. Para poder insertar el valor dentro de la regex puedes utilizar las [plantillas literales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
const replaceData = (data, keyword, replacedata) => {
  const regex = new RegExp(`{${keyword}}`, 'g');
  return data.replace(regex, replacedata);
}

console.log(replaceData('Hola, {nombre}! Cómo estás? Hasta luego {nombre}', 'nombre', 'Alejandro'));
console.log(replaceData('Hola, {}! Cómo estás? Hasta luego {nombre}', 'nombre', 'Alejandro'));
```

Comment: sos dios <3  me sirvio a la perfeccion.

Comment: Nada, solo tienes que ir conociendo el lenguaje aunque no está de más tener una ayuda. Que bueno que te sirvió.